# Create composite index with ServiceStack

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I would like to create a composite index using `CreateIndex()` like I can do this for a single column index, e.g.:

```
db.CreateIndex<NetworkPart>(np => np.NetworkId);
```

Is that even possible?

My class looks like this and I want to to create the newly added composite index on the already existing database table:

```
[CompositeIndex(true, nameof(NetworkPart1), nameof(NetworkPart2))]
public class NetworkPart
{
    [Required]
    [Index]
    public Guid NetworkId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string NetworkPart1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string NetworkPart2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I can only see to do it this way without the need of an extra tool:

```
var createIndexStatements = db.GetDialectProvider().ToCreateIndexStatements(typeof(NetworkPart));
var createIndexStatement = createIndexStatements.FirstOrDefault(stmt => stmt.Contains("uidx_networkpart_networkpart1_networkpart2"));
db.ExecuteSql(createIndexStatement);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `[CompositeIndex]` attribute is only used to define the table definition that OrmLite creates with `db.CreateTable<T>`, i.e. they're not used to create indexes at runtime.

Comment: I know but I added this index after that table had been created. Now I need to "migrate" the existing table matching the changed class. Currently I did it this way: `var createIndexStatements = db.GetDialectProvider().ToCreateIndexStatements(typeof(NetworkPart));
var createIndexStatement = createIndexStatements.FirstOrDefault(stmt => stmt.Contains("uidx_networkpart_networkpart1_networkpart2"));
db.ExecuteSql(createIndexStatement);`

Comment: [FluentMigrator](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator) is a good candidate for this kind of task.

Comment: @labilbe thanks but I would like to achieve this without the need of an extra tool. I can use ServiceStack's `CreateIndex()` to add an index on just one column the same I would like to do with a composite index.